# Getting error in App open ads from fullScreenContentCallback

Tags: java, android, admob

Based on this guideline from google https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open-ads#show_ad, I should be giving my code a fullscreen callback, but it seems like there is something wrong.
i get this error in appOpenAd.show(currentActivity, fullScreenContentCallback):

method show in class AppOpenAd cannot be applied to given types,
required: Activity
found: Activity,FullScreenContentCallback

here is the code:

```
public class AppOpenManager implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
  private static boolean isShowingAd = false;

  public void showAdIfAvailable() {
    if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

      FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
          new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
              AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
              isShowingAd = false;
              fetchAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}

            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
              isShowingAd = true;
            }
          };

      appOpenAd.show(currentActivity, fullScreenContentCallback); //this is where i get the error

    } else {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
      fetchAd();
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, they changed it.

You should change that line with these code to make the error disappear:

```
appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);
```